# How do I create a custom four button control with useful bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to make a clicker game in WPF based on [CivClicker](http://civclicker.sourceforge.net/civclicker/civclicker.html)  Mostly just a clone right now but... I hope to expand on the concept in the future.

It is mostly to practice and explore more complex MVVM and xaml problem solving. As you can see in the link, there are a lot of repeating buttons and I want to streamline that somehow.

My current solution is garbage but it is somewhat working. It started as a one command per unique button, not very clean. Then, with the CommandParameter, I cut down the commands to one per building object and had the CommandParameter take the number of buildings I wanted to purchase, a bit more clean. In my current iteration, I only have one command for all of purchase buttons related to the buildings. I am using Multibinding to bind static buildingtype and the amount of buildings to purchase.

My current 4 button purchase mechanic looks like this.

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="{Binding BuyTentCommand}" Content="Build Tent" Width="120" ToolTip="2 skins, 2 wood: +1 max pop.">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MConverter}">
                        <Binding Source="1"/> //Amount of buildings
                        <Binding Source="0"/> //Building ID
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding BuyTentCommand}" Content=" x10 " Margin="2,0">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MConverter}">
                        <Binding Source="10"/>
                        <Binding Source="0"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding BuyTentCommand}" Content=" x100 " Margin="2,0">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MConverter}">
                        <Binding Source="100"/>
                        <Binding Source="0"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding BuyTentCommand}" Content=" x1000 " Margin="2,0">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MConverter}">
                        <Binding Source="1000"/>
                        <Binding Source="0"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

Repeating that piece of code 16 times(or more), is not really ideal in any scenario. If anyone can show me an working example on how to make something like this in to a single reusable UserContol or something, I will be very grateful.

*I edited my question to be a bit more generic/conceptual.*

*BTW, first code-post ever on here and please be lenient and I would appreciate any and all suggestions for improvements on the post format.*

Comment: What kind of object does `MConverter` return? Since all the Bindings in all your MultiBindings just have constants, you don't really need bindings for that: The purpose of a `Binding` is to monitor the source and target properties for changes, and update one from the other as needed.

Comment: The usual way to do a bunch of very similar things is an itemscontrol. Bind itemssource to a collection of viewmodels which expose a command each. They each encapsulate any logic necessary. Your commandparameter bindings look kind of weird.

Comment: Yeah, I know that the bindings are weird. It is probably my lack of understanding the full scope of how to use them. It started as a one command per unique button. Then, with the CommandParameter, I cut down the commands to one per building object and had the CommandParameter take the number of buildings I wanted to purchase. And in this iteration I only have one command for all of purchase buttons related to the buildings, that relays to a method that takes a string array with the values passed from the CommandParameter. The converter only makes a string array of the MultiBinding.